# Having difficulties with adding items to unordered list with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

So I'm trying to retrieve data about countries from an Api (https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all)
Languages are displayed like this:

```
languages: {
  afr: "Afrikaans",
  eng: "English",
  nbl: "Southern Ndebele",
  nso: "Northern Sotho",
  sot: "Southern Sotho",
  ssw: "Swazi",
  tsn: "Tswana",
  tso: "Tsonga",
  ven: "Venda",
  xho: "Xhosa",
  zul: "Zulu"
}
```

my code so far is:

```
const langs = Object.values(country["languages"]) //create array of languages

 console.log(langs) 
 return ( 
   <ul>
     {langs.map(each => {
//if i add console.log(each) here, it returns all of the languages in console
     <li>
       {each} doesn't display at all
     </li>
   })}
   </ul>
)
```

If you could tell me what am I doing wrong, I'd greatly appreciate it.
Thanks in advance <3

Comment: Are you returning the JSX from the `map` callback?

Comment: @ggorlen yes, i'm trying to lol

Comment: So you did `return <li>{each}</li>`? Can you update the code to show the exact component as a [mcve]? Thanks.

Comment: In your map, you are using curly brackets in callback, thats why you'll have t add `return` keyword to actually return jsx  `return <li>{each}</li>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your code seems to be that you aren't returning the JSX in the `map` function.

To fix this, there are two solutions.

---

**1. Use brackets (`()`) in the callback**

The first solution is to use brackets in the callback.

The brackets will make it so that it will return the value passed into the callback.

To use this, you can use the code below.

```js
langs.map((each) => (
  <li>{each}</li>
));
```

The only difference in this code is that you are returning it straight away, denoted by the brackets.

If you would like to make this a one-liner, you can use this code.

```js
langs.map((each) => <li>{each}</li>);
```

This will do the same thing; return the JSX in the arrow function.

---

**2. Use the `return` keyword**

The second option is to use the `return` keyword.

You can use this to return the JSX so that the `map` function can use it.

Its usage is very simple.

```js
langs.map((each) => {
  return <li>{each}</li>;
});
```

This simply returns the JSX to the `map` function for it to use.

---

In conclusion, the issue is that you aren't returning the JSX in the `map` function.

There are two solutions for this.

1. Use brackets in the callback
2. Use the `return` keyword